# Update PHP from 5.6.31 to 5.6.36

Tags: php, wamp

I want to update php from 5.6.31 to 5.6.36 under Wamp 2.4.9 so i followed these steps

1)Download binaries on php.net

2)Extract all files in a new folder : C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.36/

3)Copy the wampserver.conf, Php.ini, PhpForAPPache from php folder (like php/php5.5.31/) to the new folder

4)Select the new version and restart sever

But The server don't start with orange icon

Comment: why can't you install new wamp?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Wamp is installed in a production environment so i prefer keeping the server .sure it is a problem of compatibility?

Comment: Why do you prefer sticking to old versions, but want to upgrade PHP?

Comment: Yes i want to upgrade to version 5.6.36 with version 2.4.9 appache

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: I'm using WAMPServer 2.5

Answer (score 3):

Instead of editing everything manually and potentially making a mistake, `Wamp` is also providing a way to do it automatically.

I can go [there](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and choose the PHP version you need.
If dependencies are needed, the program will also tell you what to do.